# "Music notes" or "Musical notes"?

Tags: word-choice

In Wikipedia, it's more like "Music notes" or maybe that's intended to make the title simpler. It seems that both are correct. Are there any differences?

Comment: Please could you give some context, such as a complete sentence which is to contain this phrase?

Comment: Context is essential. (1) *The **music** notes are written in a binder. (2) The **musical** notes put me to sleep.* (3) *The **music** notes are **musical**.* (4) *The **music notes** are **jarring**.* (5) *The **musical** was sold out.* (6) *The **music** had not been composed.*

Comment: @JasonBassford No context, unfortunately. I've just seen them in different places and was confused.